# Ruby/Rails: Reopening vs Overwriting a Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, namespaces

I want to add a method to a Rails model, to be used in testing. If I do this

```
class Model
  def something_new
    do_something
  end
end
```

in the Rails console or in a file loaded at run time, Model is overwritten rather than modified. If I put something like `v = Model.class`before the lines above, the new method is successfully added to the existing class. Apparently the reference is needed to signal that an existing class is being re-opened.

On the other hand, one can add a method to, say, Fixnum without having to refer to it first. What is going on here, and what is the usual way to ensure that an existing class is re-opened and modified rather than being overwritten?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you're not requiring the class before using it. When you write `Model.class` and there is no Model class, Rails automagically brings in Model for you. If you just write `class Model`, it just sees that as a class definition. Just doing `require 'model'` should work.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. When I saw that Model class was already recognized, I didn't realize that it was only "automagically" recognized.

Comment: This worked for me in combination with directing Rails to find the file I wanted to `require` similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348751/how-to-require-file-from-gem-which-are-not-under-lib-directory

Answer (score 6):

Use `class_eval`, that way you will be reopening the class the right way.
Here's a very good article on [reopening classes](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2007/01/17/reopening-ruby-classes-2/).

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition to **Chuck**'s answer here is the quote from Rails [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#constants-after-the-class-and-module-keywords):

> 6.1.1 Constants after the class and module Keywords
>   Ruby performs a lookup for the constant that follows a class or module keyword because it needs to know if the class or module is going to be created or reopened.
>
> If the constant is not defined at that point it is not considered to be a missing constant, autoloading is **not** triggered.