# How to require file from `gem` which are not under `lib` directory?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, rubocop

I want to write spec for my [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#custom-cops) custom cop. This gem has handy helpers defined [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/spec/support/cop_helper.rb). I want to require it. How to achieve what?

I've tried to use `Gem.find_files`, and this gives me ability to require any file in that gem, but only under `lib` directory.

For example:

```
# this requires ...gems/rubocop-0.29.1/lib/rubocop/formatter/formatter_set.rb
require Gem.find_files('rubocop/formatter/formatter_set.rb').first
# but I need ...gems/rubocop-0.29.1/spec/support/cop_helper.rb
```

The following describes why I need it. I have `spec/rubocop/my_custom_cop_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'
require ? # What I should I write?

RSpec.describe RuboCop::Cop::Style::MyCustomCop do
  it 'some test' do
    inspect_source(cop, 'method(arg1, arg2)') # This helper I want to use from rubocop spec helpers
  end
end
```

When I try plain require:

```
require 'rubocop/spec/support/cop_helper'
```

I receive error:

```
/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274
:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubocop/spec/support/cop_helper
```

Comment: you want to require what? If you need custom functionality that is eager loaded you should place this in initializers or add the files needed to autoload_paths. Otherwise this question does not offer a lot to go on.

Comment: I want to require `rubocop/spec/support/cop_helper.rb` from `rubocop` `gem` in my `spec/rubocop/my_custom_cop_spec.rb`

Comment: have you tried just requiring that file? e.g. `require rubocop/spec/support/cop_helper`

Comment: Is rubocop installed?

Comment: Yes, I have it in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a solution that I think is a little more syntactically elegant:

```
gem_dir = Gem::Specification.find_by_name("my_gem").gem_dir
require "#{gem_dir}/spec"
```

Answer (score 5):

I was so blinded, I already have path to file and able to get relative from it.

```
require 'pathname'
rubocop_path = Pathname.new(Gem.find_files('rubocop.rb').first).dirname
rubocop_path # => ...gems/rubocop-0.29.1/lib
require "#{rubocop_path}/../spec/support/cop_helper.rb"
```