# Is it possible to require a single file in a Ruby gem rather than the main gem entry point?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have inherited a Ruby gem that takes a long time to load. In some cases, I don't need to load the entire gem, and need access to only one file in the gem which has no dependencies on any other files in the gem.

Is there a way to `require` just this one file? I can modify the gemspec if necessary. That is, instead of:

```
require 'my_gem'
```

...I'd like to do:

```
require 'my_gem/a/b/c/my_file'
```

Comment: You could check out [How to require file from `gem` which are not under `lib` directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348751/how-to-require-file-from-gem-which-are-not-under-lib-directory)

Comment: Yes you can just try `require 'my_gem/path/to/file'`.

Comment: That's what I thought too, and when I tried it on another gem, that worked, but it didn't work with the particular gem I was originally trying to do this on. There may be something in the gemspec that causes it to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to require a single file in a Ruby gem?

`require` always loads a single file.

In other words, it is not only possible to require a single file, it is actually impossible *not to*.

Comment: Not really true, requiring a gem in Ruby usually results in the loading/requiring of most or all of the Ruby files in that gem, no?

Comment: `require` requires one file. Period. Of course, that file is allowed to contain any code whatsoever, including calls to `require`.

Comment: I see now that my question was unclear. Thanks for pointing this out. This in no way solves my problem, so I don't really consider this an answer, but helped me express the problem more clearly.